# Formdata in react and ulpoading it in NestJs & Internal Server Error

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, nestjs, form-data

> I am getting an error at the backend that:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')
at ProductService.createProduct (E:\QUEPER\Nest\admin_portal_backend\src\product\product.service.ts:23:29)
```

AND

```
xhr.js:251     POST http://localhost:3000/products 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:251
xhr @ xhr.js:49
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:51
request @ Axios.js:148
httpMethod @ Axios.js:187
wrap @ bind.js:5
saveProduct @ admin_page.js:28
handleConfirm @ admin_page.js:48
onSubmit @ admin_page.js:173
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
    admin_page.js:31 AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code:             'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

> while loging statement in createProduct method of controller gives:

```
{ dataA: {}, dataB: [ { color: 'c1', size: 's1' } ] }
undefined
```

> here dataA is showing as empty object and image parameter is giving undefined value.
> Idk why this is happening.
> I want the image's data to be properly stored at backend and whenever i try to retrieve it, proper image should be displayed on front end.

> -------React code

## React code:

> Here in parameter i m getting data,which is an object and it's containing the products's data(image,productName,regularPrice,salePrice & dec) and the
> variation's related to the data (variation is array [{color,size}]).

```
const saveProduct = async (data) => {
  try {
    console.log(data);
    const formdata=new  FormData();
    formdata.append('image',data.productData.image);
    formdata.append('productName',data.productData.productName);
    formdata.append('desc',data.productData.desc);
    formdata.append('regularPrice',data.productData.regularPrice);
    formdata.append('salePrice',data.productData.salePrice);
    

    const data1={
      dataA: formdata,
      dataB: data.variationData
    }
    console.log(data1);
    for (const entry of data1.dataA.entries()) {
      console.log(entry);
    }
    // Convert productData to JSON string and append it

    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/products', data1);
    return response.data; // The saved product data
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    // throw error;
  }
};
```

## > This is the data I m sending from the front end:

```
{productData: {…}, variationData: Array(1)}
productData
: 
desc
: 
"d1"
image
: 
File {name: 'download.jpeg', lastModified: 1689319709094, lastModifiedDate: Fri Jul 14 2023 12:28:29 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 4698, …}
productName
: 
"p1"
regularPrice
: 
"rp1"
salePrice
: 
"sp1"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
variationData
: 
Array(1)
0
: 
{color: 'c1', size: 's1'}
length
: 
1
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

## Nest Js:

## main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);

  // Enable CORS
  app.enableCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3001', // frontend URL
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    credentials: true,
  });

  console.log('bootstrap');

  // Configure Multer for file uploading
  const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: './uploads',
    filename: (req, file, cb: (error: Error | null, filename: string) => void) => {
      const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
      const extension = path.extname(file.originalname);
      const filename = `${uniqueSuffix}${extension}`;
      cb(null, filename);
    },
  });
  // Handle file upload for 'image' field
  app.use(multer({ storage }).single('image'));

  // Serve uploaded files as static files
  const uploadsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'uploads');
  app.useStaticAssets(uploadsPath, {
    prefix: '/uploads/',
  });
  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

## product.controller.ts:

```
@Controller('products')
export class ProductController {
  constructor(private readonly productService: ProductService) {}

  @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('image')) // Handle 'image' field file upload
  async createProduct(@Body() createProductDto: CreateProductDto, @UploadedFile() image: Express.Multer.File): Promise<any> {
    try {
      
      console.log(createProductDto);
      console.log(image);
      const product = await this.productService.createProduct(createProductDto, image);
      return product;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
  
}
```

## product.service.ts:

```
async createProduct(createProductDto: CreateProductDto, image: Express.Multer.File): Promise<Product> {
    try {
      const { productData, variationData } = createProductDto;
  
      const product = this.productRepository.create(productData);
      product.image = image.filename;
  
      const createdProduct = await this.productRepository.save(product);

      const filteredVariationData = variationData.filter(
        variation => variation.color !== '' || variation.size !== ''
      );
  
      if (filteredVariationData.length > 0) {
        const createdVariations = filteredVariationData.map(variation => {
          const createdVariation = this.variationRepository.create({
            ...variation,
            product: createdProduct, // Set the product relationship
          });
          return createdVariation;
        });
  
        await this.variationRepository.save(createdVariations);
  
        createdProduct.variations = createdVariations;
      }
  
      return createdProduct;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error); // Log the error
      throw error; // Re-throw the error
    }
  }
```

## Create-product.dto.ts:

```
export class CreateProductDto {
    productData: {
      productName: string;
      desc: string;
      regularPrice: string;
      salePrice: string;
      image: string;
    };
    variationData: {
      color: string;
      size: string;
    }[];
  }
```

> and i have two entities in database -> Product and Variation

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add `app.use(multer().sinlge())` to your `main.ts`. That's essentially what is happening under the hood of the `FileInterceptor`, and adding it a second time is most likely causing an issue with Nest trying to pass on `req.uploadedFile` from the interceptor to the controller.

If you need to configure the storage specifically, you can use the `MulterModule` in the same module as the controller lives